# The most efficient way for convert schedule calendar to crontab schedule rule

Tags: cron, scheduled-tasks

I have a schedule calendar like this

[image]

(The blue area is selected time)

and it will return a JSON string like

```
 {"val": [
  { "day": 1, "start_at": 0, "duration": 4},
  { "day": 1, "start_at": 5, "duration": 6},
  { "day": 1, "start_at": 19, "duration": 3},
  { "day": 2, "start_at": 0, "duration": 2 },
  { "day": 2, "start_at": 4, "duration": 1 },
  { "day": 2, "start_at": 6, "duration": 1 },
  { "day": 2, "start_at": 9, "duration": 3 },
  { "day": 3, "start_at":0, "duration": 23}
]}
```

then I need to convert it to Crontab schedule command to do some schedule task.

like

```
* [0,1,3,4,7,8] * * Mon 
* [4,6,7] * * Tue
......
```

But this way will generate 7 schedule rules and generate 7 schedule tasks , I think it is not efficient.

Is it possible to convert it to one schedule rule and only generate one schedule task?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your picture you have nothing which can be "optimized". You need to have cron record for every event. And using syntax like `* 2 * * * command` you run your command every minute.

And the proper format for `cron` is:

```
* * * * * command
```

where 1st `*` is for minutes, second for hours, third for days of month, fourth for months and last for days of week